# Any other PaaS provider offers feature like Windows Azure's *worker role* on preconfigured environment?

Tags: daemon, environment, execution, paas

Windows Azure worker role support daemon-like execution on preconfigured/managed environment. Any other service provider offers this feature?

Answer (score 1):

Heroku has something similar to worker roles called Delayed Jobs http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/delayed-job. I am looking for something like this too.